# C++: How to add pthreads in a loop but not "pause" the loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am learning pthread but I have one problem. 
I would like to add a thread inside loop so that the thread function can be implemented separately and the loop doesn't pause till the thread function finished.

Here is my sample code:

```
void * numbers(void * a){
    cout << "---------------------"<<endl;
    int * args = ( int*) a;
    int sum =0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    sum++;
}

int main(){

int sum2 = 0;
while(1){
    sum2 = sum2 + 3;
    cout << sum2 << endl;
    int num;
    pthread_t thread_id2;
    pthread_create( &thread_id2, NULL, numbers, (void*) &num);
    void *status1;
    pthread_join( thread_id2, NULL);
}


return -1;
}
```

The result of the code, as shown below,  is not what I want.

```
3
---------------------
6
---------------------
9
---------------------
```

My idea is the loop keeps summing up sum2 while thread function "numbers" is running. So the result I need should be something like:

```
3
6
9
12
-------------------
15
18 and so on
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Don't `pthread_join` in the loop. Join blocks the calling thread until the joined thread completes. [Read the `pthread_join` documentation for more details.](http://www.manpages.info/linux/pthread_join.3.html)

Comment: Indeed, pausing the loop is *the entire purpose of `pthread_join`*. (But you do need to call either `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` at some point, or you'll get a memory leak)

Comment: I don't really get your example but it seems o me that what you need is an array of `pthread_t` handles and two loops: The first loop `pthread_create`s all threads in the array and the second `pthread_join`s them again. Between the two loops, you can do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: look here for how to run threads and wait for them all to finish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624545/how-to-make-main-thread-wait-for-all-child-threads-finish

Answer (score 1):

call pthread_detach(thread_id2) instead of pthread_join function.

Comment: `pthread_detach` won't cut it here. `main` would run through the loop and then exit the program, leaving the still-running threads in a bad position. OP needs to record all of the started threads, then join them after the starting loop all to ensure they all manage to complete before exiting.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I need to return value from the pthread function? Because pthread_detach cannot return the value from the pthread function....What can I use instead of pthread_join( thread_id2, &status1)?

Comment: Call pthread_join at the point where you require the result. It'll wait at that point until the thread will end. And the thread will call pthread_exit at the end. Hope that will help you