# Unable to create pthread for function in C

Tags: c, pthreads

Am new to C, am trying to create thread using below code but i unable to create thread, Can any one tell me where i am going wrong...
It is not going into 'if' loop and not calling 'myfunction'

```
void *myfunction() {
   //my code
}

void createThreadForMyFunction(void) {
   pthread_t thread_ID;
   if(pthread_create(&thread_ID, NULL, myfunction, NULL)) {
         printf("pthread_create");
    }
}
```

Comment: [`On  success,  pthread_create()  returns  0`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

Comment: @red0ct  But why function is not getting called.....do i need to call the function explicitly after thread creation..

Comment: We can't deduce much else from your question. Please read the help pages on how to create a minimal complete example for the problem and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

[`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) returns `0` on success. So you could add `!` to your `if` statement or do something like:

```
if (pthread_create...) {
    perror("CREATE");
    return;
} 
/* other code */
```

To make the `main` function wait child with id `threadID` you also may just do `pthread_join(threadID, NULL);` after thread creation without using `sleep` and friends.
[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624545/how-to-make-main-thread-wait-for-all-child-threads-finish).

Answer (score 1):

Return value of [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) is an `int` that is 0 on success. So if you are not entering in your `if` function, it is because your thread was successfully created.

So your function `myFunction` is actually called, in your new thread.

Note that if your main thread (the one executing `createThreadForMyFunction`) end too quickly, it kills the child thread (the one executing `myFunction`) before it prints anything, and you won't see if your thread was successfully created. Try to add a [usleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) after the thread creation in order to give some time to your new thread to show itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
void* myfunction(void *arg)
{
  // do somthing
}

int main(void)
{
   pthread_t thread_ID;
   int err;

        err = pthread_create(&thread_ID, NULL, &myfunction, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
    }

    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```