# Thread don't terminate their job

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a concurrent C program where I want to wait for all threads to finish in the `main()`.

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624560/5379444), I wrote the following code in `main()`:

```
// Create threads
pthread_t cid[num_mappers];
int t_iter;
for (t_iter = 0; t_iter < num_mappers; t_iter++){
    pthread_create(&(cid[t_iter]), NULL, &map_consumer, NULL);
}

// Wait for all threads to finish
for (t_iter = 0; t_iter < num_mappers; t_iter++){
    printf("Joining %d\n", t_iter);
    int result = pthread_join(cid[t_iter], NULL);
}

printf("Done mapping.\n");
```

The function passed into threads is defined as:

```
// Consumer function for mapping phase
void *map_consumer(void *arg){
    while (1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g_lock);
        if (g_cur >= g_numfull){
            // No works to do, just quit
            return NULL;
        }

        // Get the file name
        char *filename = g_job_queue[g_cur];
        g_cur++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_lock);

        // Do the mapping
        printf("%s\n", filename);
        g_map(filename);
    }
}
```

The threads are all successfully created and executed, but the join loop will never finish if `num_mappers` >= 2.

Comment: What happens in `map_consumer` when `g_cur` is big enough to quit ? does the thread keeps its `pthread_mutex_lock` ?

Comment: @grorel Oh I see! I have to `unlock` before returning, otherwise all other threads are just waiting for getting the lock. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return without unlocking the mutex:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_lock);
    if (g_cur >= g_numfull){
        // No works to do, just quit
        return NULL;  <-- mutex is still locked here
    }

    // Get the file name
    char *filename = g_job_queue[g_cur];
    g_cur++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_lock);
```

So only one thread ever returns and ends - the first one, but since it never unlocks the mutex, the other threads remain blocked.

You need something more like

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_lock);
    if (g_cur >= g_numfull){
        // No works to do, just quit
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_lock);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Get the file name
    char *filename = g_job_queue[g_cur];
    g_cur++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_lock);
```

Comment: It would be neat to have some sort of RAII or `try`/`finally` in C for these situations, but I guess that's why C++ exists.

Comment: @Groo: Exactly my thought too, RAII rules! ;) I have many times successfully used C++ in combination with pure pthreads, in cases where the thin std::thread layer on top of pthreads hides some more exotic pthreads settings/config I need.