# Multithreading in C with CLion (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, parallel-processing, clion

I have a section of code which is really time-consuming (~2s), and can be executed without the last one have finished.

```c
for (x = last; x <= end && !found; x++) {
  found = combine(combinaciones, x, end, &current);
}
```

Note that `combine()` it's the function I was talking about. But before the loop starts again (this for it's inside another loop) all the functions must have finished.

Also, `combine()` receives some arguments, `combinaciones` it's a pointer, and `current` an integer (by reference). The integer gets modified over time (and must get modified on the other active functions) and `combinaciones` it's a linked list (size of which is `current-1`). The 2nd and 3rd argument are just integers. The return it's a boolean that terminates the loop, but I don't matter if they make some extra operations.

I stress the importance of `current`. If `current` is equal to 5, `combinaciones`'s 5th element will be the created, and then `current` will be 6. I mean that if two functions are allocating memory they souldn't allocate to the same position.

If that can't be done I can make the operations in parallel, and then allocate the memory on the `main()`.

So, I started searching about multithreading and I found `<pthread.h>`, but it only worked on Linux (not on CLion). I found something caled fork, I don't know either if can be used. **Would you tell me a Windows multithreading API, with an example, and the CLion implementation?**

The code is huge and I don't think that would help a lot, with I have said should be enought. However, if something is unclear let me know. The code itself it's published on [GitHub](https://github.com/rogermiranda1000/combinacions), but the (few) comments it has are in Spanish.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should just use Wsl and use wsl toolchain , for more look here :https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html

Comment: @Singh OK, now `pthread.h` works, but I still don't have the code. I'll try to do it on my own, if I succeed I will update the post.

Comment: this maybe could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624560/9386720

Comment: regarding: `typedef unsigned char *Encrypted;`  It is a very poor programming practice to hide pointers in a `typedef` statement

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct {`   Most debuggers use a struct `tag` name to access the individual fields within the struct.  Therefore, strongly suggest giving the struct a `tag` name

Comment: in function: `myFun()`, the preferred method of returning from a thread is not : `return NULL;` but rather: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: in file: `paraleling.h`  the prototype for a function that does not receive an parameters needs to have `void` between the parens. otherwise, the compiler produces a function that can receive any number of parameters (including none)  Suggest replacing: `void paralel();`  with `void paralel( void );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("[e] On joining thread\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest:  `fprintf( stderr, "[e] On joining thread\n %s\n", strerror( <the number returned from pthread_join> ) );`  Of course this means that number needs to be actually saved into a variable.  from the MAN page: *On success, pthread_join() returns 0; on error,  it  returns  an  error number.*

Comment: regarding: `printf("[v] Combinaciones: %lu\n", *comb);`  This means the reading/writing of the variable needs to be protected, so no 'race' conditions result.  Suggest using a `pthread_mutex` for this purpose.  Also suggest `sleep(30)` be replaced with the call to lock the mutex and after the following printf() statement a call to unlock the mutex

Comment: in function: `processParalel()`  once a call to `pthread_create()` fails, it is very unlikely that another call to that function will succeed.

Comment: in `paraleling.c`, the variable `start` is declared by: `clock_t start;`  however, it is being set via: `start = (float)clock();`  The cast to `float` needs to be removed.

Comment: when calculating an elapsed time in seconds, use the function: `difftime()`  so the calculation would be:  `printf("[v] Tiempo de ejecucion medio: %.2fs\n", difftime( clock() , start) / CLOCKS_PER_SECOND / THREADS);`  which allows for the value returned by `clock()` needs to be treated as an unsigned value

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char **argw) {`  Because those parameters are not used, the compiler will output two warnings messages about unused parameters.  To fix these warnings, use the other valid signature for `main()`  `int main( void )`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: @user3629249 sorry for the reply delay. Thanks for all. I'll consider them for future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Wsl (as @Singh said) I could use `pthread.h`. Then I just adapted my code. A very annoying bug that I had was that "IDs" (`current` variable) were assigned non-continuously (the first thread had "3", and the second one had "2"). I was able to fix it by using a global variable (`pthread_mutex_t`) and `pthread_mutex_lock()`, `pthread_mutex_unlock()`. For more information you can still check my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/rogermiranda1000/combinacions).

Comment: I'm glad that you solve your problem by yourself, early i forgot to tell you about   pthread mutex but im happy you figured it out ;).